# How can I view the number of locks held by MySQL InnoDB, when the total is larger than 10?

Tags: mysql

We have a problem where our ORM is locking more tables than I'd expect. This is causing deadlock on our production system which I'm struggling to diagnose.

I can see, using either `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` or by using the innotop tool the top 10 locks, but I'm unable to see the rest.

Here's the head and tail of an example output from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
--TRANSACTION 1832883, ACTIVE 1728 sec
29 lock struct(s), heap size 3520, 14 row lock(s), undo log entries 10

...

10 LOCKS PRINTED FOR THIS TRX: SUPPRESSING FURTHER PRINTS
```

How can I view the locks beyond the first 10?

Perconda has the `innodb_show_locks_held` variable - is there an alternative for MySQL? I'm using MySQL 5.7 in development if that's relevant.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: A "deadlock" would show two transactions indicating that one of them was rolled back.  Perhaps you did not mean "deadlock"?

Comment: I am trying to diagnose the deadlock, which does indeed show two transactions. I know one of the transactions of those two is a simple one liner and the other is a more complicated transaction involving more queries. It is the latter transaction which contains more than 10 locks and that is the transaction I'm trying to understand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the SYS schema that ships with MySQL 5.7.  This will show you lock waits (more useful than locks) in a pretty easy to diagnose way:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sys.innodb_lock_waits\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                wait_started: 2014-11-11 13:39:20
                    wait_age: 00:00:07
               wait_age_secs: 7
                locked_table: `db1`.`t1`
                locked_index: PRIMARY
                 locked_type: RECORD
              waiting_trx_id: 867158
         waiting_trx_started: 2014-11-11 13:39:15
             waiting_trx_age: 00:00:12
     waiting_trx_rows_locked: 0
   waiting_trx_rows_modified: 0
                 waiting_pid: 3
               waiting_query: UPDATE t1 SET val = val + 1 WHERE id = 2
             waiting_lock_id: 867158:2363:3:3
           waiting_lock_mode: X
             blocking_trx_id: 867157
                blocking_pid: 4
              blocking_query: UPDATE t1 SET val = val + 1 + SLEEP(10) WHERE id = 2
            blocking_lock_id: 867157:2363:3:3
          blocking_lock_mode: X
        blocking_trx_started: 2014-11-11 13:39:11
            blocking_trx_age: 00:00:16
    blocking_trx_rows_locked: 1
  blocking_trx_rows_modified: 1
     sql_kill_blocking_query: KILL QUERY 4
sql_kill_blocking_connection: KILL 4
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This query returns an empty set (even though `SHOW ENGINE....` returns as above) - is there something I'm missing? This is an updated 5.5 to 5.7 database if that's relevant.

Comment: To clarify: this query is lock waits (not locks).  A deadlock will start out as a lock wait, unfortunately there is not a way to see raw locks besides show engine innodb status.